# Change URL in script and run script again

Tags: variables, autohotkey

we are using this script;

```
run "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://SOMEURL.shtml**
Sleep, 10000
Send, %ROUTERUN%{tab}
Sleep, 1000
Send, %ROUTERPW%
Sleep, 1000
Send, {Tab}{Tab}{Space}
Sleep, 10000
Send, #Up
Send, {F5}
Sleep, 20000
Click, 1041, 575
Send, %CODE%
Sleep, 1000
Click, 1613, 983
Sleep, 1000
If WinExist Message from webpage
    WinActivate
Sleep, 1000
Click, 392, 153
Sleep, 1000
If WinExist Message from webpage
    WinActivate
Click, 219, 153
Sleep, 8000
Send, !{F4}
Sleep, 1000
FormatTime, TimeString,, LongDate
FormatTime, TimeString2,, Time
FileAppend, %VES1% %TimeString% %TimeString2% D:\Test.txt
```

What we would like to accomplish is, when the script is finished, to run the script again but this time with another URL on the first line. 
And that times 38. 
Ofcourse I can copy/paste the script 38 times and change the line manually, but maybe there is a way of solving this with a variable or loop or something like that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [array](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/Objects.htm#Usage_Simple_Arrays) and a loop to accomplish this. This example uses [AHK_L](http://l.autohotkey.net/)

```
arr := []
arr[1] := "www.google.com"
arr[2] := "yahoo.com"
arr[3] := "www.amazon.com" 

Loop % arr.MaxIndex()
{
    site := arr[A_Index]
    Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %site%
    ;;; Other code here ;;;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On top of the answer from Elliot, when you use Google Chrome, you can "detect" if the page is ready downloading by monitoring the mouse status (pointer or hourglass) through the following code:

```
while (A_Cursor = "AppStarting") ; While hourglass do sleep else continue
    Sleep, 500 ; Wait 500 ms then run while again...
Your next lines of code....
```

This way you don't have to put long sleep timers in your code, just to be sure that the page is downloaded...

Also, if you want to store the login & password per site, you could use "multi-dimensional" arrays

```
Arr[1,1] := "www.google.com"
Arr[1,2] := "abc@google.com"
Arr[1,3] := "s3cr3tp@ssw0rd"
Arr[2,1] := "yahoo.com"
Arr[2,2] := "abc@yahoo.com"
Arr[2,3] := "s3cr3tp@ssw0rd"
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I will have a look at this as well. Cheers.